# Ckfinder fileupload issue in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor, ckfinder

I've got a problem with ckfinder in mvc project.

I moved ckfinder folder in ckeditor and edited paths in config.ascx  like this:

```
   BaseUrl = "/Content/";
   BaseDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/");
```

I added js files to _Layout.cshtml:

```
       <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.js")"></script>
```

And finally my Index.cshtml

```
   @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    CKEDITOR.replace('ckEditor', {
        skin: 'kama',
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html")',
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images")',
        filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash")',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: '@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=Files")',
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=Images")',
        filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '@Url.Content("~/ckeditor/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash")'
    });
});
```

```
  <h2>MVC 3 CKEditor and CKFinder </h2>

  @Html.TextArea("ckEditor")
```

Ckeditor is working fine but when i try to upload a image (using ckfinder) i'm getting error=>
An exception of type 'CKFinder.Connector.ConnectorException' occurred in CKFinder.dll but was not handled in user code
[image]

And my project Files=>
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can't get it to work either. If i call the CKFinder it gives me this error:

'The uploading of a file is not possible at the moment. Contact the system owner and check the CKFinder configuration file'

I think it has something to do with permissions on the folder? To configure CKFinder for asp.net they say:

'Make the user files folder writable for the Internet user. On Windows systems, give write permissions to the IUSR_ user.'

http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Installation

I don't have a IUSR_ user on my local windows system. I just have to create one?

**Edit:**

I've got it solved! I've rebuild the CKFinder solution situated in the _source folder and then copied the dll file to my application. Now everything is working fine!

There was also something wrong with my permissions on the folder for the uploaded images.